# DCMTK StoreSCP.exe writing files to memory

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am using storescp.exe(http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/storescp.html) as StoreSCP of my DICOM application. I need to send the DICOM files to storescp where no dcm file is generated. Could you please inform the switch statement for preventing file generation on store operation?

Answer (score 2):

The command line option is --ignore

storescp --ignore

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried and it is working fine.